# Display youtube video using link from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need a code to display youtube video in asp.net website using link present in database

now i am using below code but its not working:-

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">


            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <span>No data was returned.</span>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <div align="center">
                    <asp:Label ID="content_headLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("content_head") %>' Font-Size="Large" Font-Bold="True"/>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="fa-file-video-o" align="center">
                <iframe src='<%#Eval("content_link") %>' runat="server" width="800" height="450"></iframe>
                <br/>
            </ItemTemplate>


        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
</div>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CampusConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [content_head], [content_link] FROM [inspire] WHERE ([type] = @type)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Video" Name="type" Type="String"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: How about simple embed in HTML : https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: what's the value you store in databases ? can you show ?

Comment: youtube link just copy and past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a youtube URL, you can emit something similar to the following HTML code to embed the video in your page:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[your video ID goes here]" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So, if your youtube video URL was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myVideoID, you'd replace the "watch?v=" with "embed/", and then use that string as the value of the `src` attribute in that `iframe` tag above.